# Multiple instances for a single database in Mirroring

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, enterprise, mirroring

Can I configure 2 different instances for a single database in database mirroring? In other words can I mirror database 1 to instance B and then mirror database 1 to instance C?!

SQL Server 2014 SP2 Enterprise Edition.

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

1) Log shipping (in theory, there is *no limit* for maximum number of secondary databases/replicas) or

2) Availability Groups (with maximum 8 secondary replicas). ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff877884.aspx

Comment: Log Shipping could not be an option as we are using 3rd party backup solution that will break the LSN if we go with native SQL T-Logs.

Comment: AG is not an option as of now, maybe later but the available HA solution is Mirroring only.

Comment: LS:I would create a custom log shipping solution. LS is just (1) backup log, (2) copy log backup and (3) restore log backup with morecovery / standby.

Comment: Regarding LS: you don't have to use SQL Server' sys procedures to configure LS. In this case, you could simple create two SQL Agent jobs on secondary server: (2) one to copy on local server log backups and, also, (3) another to restore these log backups using `WITH RECOVERY` or `WITH STANDBY = '....path.tuf'`

Comment: Thanx Bogdan for your help, regarding LS: from where I will get the t-log backups on the secondary server? from the primary of course, right? and I as mentioned before we are using a 3rd party tool for all SQL backups, and as far as I know, we cannot backup logs from 2 different sources (2 bkp chains) because @ the time of Disaster, you will not be able to restore to the latest point in time (2 bkp chains), and this is a production instance with Full Recovery Model.

Comment: AG will be implemented later on when we get the POC from the Business users + the application owners (3rd party), it`s a long story here and this will take some time, as of now it`s only Mirroring in which you cannot create 2 endpoints with different ports on a single instance.

Comment: LS: I assume that this 3rd party backup solution is used for (at least) full and log backups (maybe, also, diff ?). So, for this custom LS solution  I would copy on secondary LS server(s) log backups created with this 3rd p solution.

Comment: Note: backups = database backups